# How to Push my Postman Automation code to my Git-lab?

Tags: git, api, automation, gitlab, postman

Suppose there is a collection that consists of 10 requests and I have completed coding for 3 out of them. now, The Que is how can I Push those only 3 requests to Git Repository? We know whatever coding we in postman is cloud. So, is there any way to do this as I don't have any local files for 10 Requests?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [export your postman data](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/), which will generate json data for your collections and tests. You can then use the `newman` runner to execute those json files in GitLab's CI, or simply have your team members check them out and run them by importing them into their postman environment.

Note: Since the collections export in json, any secrets that you're storing in your postman app locally will export *in plaintext*. Don't forget to use variables instead of hard-coding your secrets.

Comment: can we do this without exporting my Postman data again and again? Say I want to push only two scripts so for this also I need to Export my collection and then do the process.

Comment: Postman actually offers a paid version that handles version control for you because of how inconvenient this is (the fork mentioned in the other answer), but there isn't really any other way to do it. Your other alternative is to split up your collection into multiple smaller collections so you don't have to export as much, but the export > stage > upload is really the only way to store them in git.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use postman fork so that you don't need to export each time you change your code

https://blog.postman.com/forking-merging-a-conflict-resolution-solution/